# How to draw crack line on egg?

Tags: modeling

I want to make Pokemon's exeggcute.
I made egg, but how to draw crack line on surface of egg?

Don't have to be really broken. It is OK just drawing a simple line on surface.
I want to know the easiest possible way.

[image]

Comment: In **Texture Paint** mode change the stroke type to **Line** in the Stroke panel. It'll alllow you draw straight precise lines.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I notice Texture Paint first time.